# Error while upgrading to 16.04: 'LC_CTYPE=fr_FR.UTF-8' is not a git command and many dependency errors

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I just upgraded to 16.04 using `sudo do-release-upgrade`.

I saw this message at the end of the process :

```
The upgrade has completed but there were errors during the upgrade process.
```

Now if I do: `$ sudo apt full-upgrade` I get this log:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Calculating upgrade...
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
38 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [O/n] Setting up keyboard-configuration (1.108ubuntu15.2) ...

git: 'LC_CTYPE=fr_FR.UTF-8' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
dpkg: error processing package keyboard-configuration (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of console-setup:
 console-setup depends on keyboard-configuration (= 1.108ubuntu15.2); however:
  Package keyboard-configuration is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package console-setup (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kbd:
 kbd depends on console-setup | console-setup-mini; however:
  Package console-setup is not configured yet.
  Package console-setup-mini is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package kbd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of console-setup-linux:
 console-setup-linux depends on kbd (>= 1.15-1ubuntu3); however:
  Package kbd is not configured yet.
 console-setup-linux depends on keyboard-configuration (= 1.108ubuntu15.2); however:
  Package keyboard-configuration is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package console-setup-linux (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-minimal:
 ubuntu-minimal depends on console-setup; however:
  Package console-setup is not configured yet.
 ubuntu-minimal depends on kbd; however:
  Package kbd is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-minimal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-core:
 xserver-xorg-core depends on keyboard-configuration; however:
  Package keyboard-configuration is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-input-evdev:
 xserver-xorg-input-evdev depends on xorg-input-abi-22; however:
  Package xorg-input-abi-22 is not installed.
  Package xserver-xorg-core which provides xorg-input-abi-22 is not configured yet.
 xserver-xorg-input-evdev depends on xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.99.902); however:
  Package xserver-xorg-core is not configured yet.
  Package xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid which provides xserver-xorg-core is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-input-evdev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-input-synaptics:
 xserver-xorg-input-synaptics depends on xorg-input-abi-22; however:
  Package xorg-input-abi-22 is not installed.
  Package xserver-xorg-core which provides xorg-input-abi-22 is not configured yet.
 xserver-xorg-input-synaptics depends on xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.99.902); however:
  Package xserver-xorg-core is not configured yet.
  Package xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid which provides xserver-xorg-core is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-input-synaptics (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse:
 xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse depends on xorg-input-abi-22; however:
  Package xorg-input-abi-22 is not installed.
  Package xserver-xorg-core which provides xorg-input-abi-22 is not configured yet.
 xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse depends on xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.99.902); however:
  Package xserver-xorg-core is not configured yet.
  Package xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid which provides xserver-xorg-core is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-input-wacom:
 xserver-xorg-input-wacom depends on xorg-input-abi-22; however:
  Package xorg-input-abi-22 is not installed.
  Package xserver-xorg-core which provides xorg-input-abi-22 is not configured yet.
 xserver-xorg-input-wacom depends on xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.99.902); however:
  Package xserver-xorg-core is not configured yet.
  Package xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid which provides xserver-xorg-core is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-input-wacom (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-input-all:
 xserver-xorg-input-all depends on xserver-xorg-input-evdev; however:
  Package xserver-xorg-input-evdev is not configured yet.
 xserver-xorg-input-all depends on xserver-xorg-input-synaptics; however:
  Package xserver-xorg-input-synaptics is not configured yet.
 xserver-xorg-input-all depends on xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse; however:
  Package xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse is not configured yet.
 xserver-xorg-input-all depends on xserver-xorg-input-wacom; however:
  Package xserver-xorg-input-wacom is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-input-all (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg:
 xserver-xorg depends on xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.2-2); however:
  Package xserver-xorg-core is not configured yet.
  Package xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid which provides xserver-xorg-core is not installed.
 xserver-xorg depends on xserver-xorg-input-all | xorg-driver-input; however:
  Package xserver-xorg-input-all is not configured yet.
  Package xorg-driver-input is not installed.
  Package xserver-xorg-input-synaptics which provides xorg-driver-input is not configured yet.
  Package xserver-xorg-input-wacom which provides xorg-driver-input is not configured yet.
  Package xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse which provides xorg-driver-input is not configured yet.
  Package xserver-xorg-input-evdev which provides xorg-driver-input is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xorg:
 xorg depends on xserver-xorg (>= 1:7.7+13ubuntu3); however:
  Package xserver-xorg is not configured yet.
  Package xserver-xorg-lts-vivid which provides xserver-xorg is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package xorg (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-desktop:
 ubuntu-desktop depends on xorg; however:
  Package xorg is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-desktop (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu:
 xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu depends on xorg-video-abi-20; however:
  Package xorg-video-abi-20 is not installed.
  Package xserver-xorg-core which provides xorg-video-abi-20 is not configured yet.
 xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu depends on xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.99.902); however:
  Package xserver-xorg-core is not configured yet.
  Package xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid which provides xserver-xorg-core is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-video-radeon:
 xserver-xorg-video-radeon depends on xorg-video-abi-20; however:
  Package xorg-video-abi-20 is not installed.
  Package xserver-xorg-core which provides xorg-video-abi-20 is not configured yet.
 xserver-xorg-video-radeon depends on xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.99.902); however:
  Package xserver-xorg-core is not configured yet.
  Package xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid which provides xserver-xorg-core is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-video-radeon (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-video-ati:
 xserver-xorg-video-ati depends on xorg-video-abi-20; however:
  Package xorg-video-abi-20 is not installed.
  Package xserver-xorg-core which provides xorg-video-abi-20 is not configured yet.
 xserver-xorg-video-ati depends on xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.99.902); however:
  Package xserver-xorg-core is not configured yet.
  Package xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid which provides xserver-xorg-core is not installed.
 xserver-xorg-video-ati depends on xserver-xorg-video-radeon; however:
  Package xserver-xorg-video-radeon is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-video-ati (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-video-fbdev:
 xserver-xorg-video-fbdev depends on xorg-video-abi-20; however:
  Package xorg-video-abi-20 is not installed.
  Package xserver-xorg-core which provides xorg-video-abi-20 is not configured yet.
 xserver-xorg-video-fbdev depends on xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.99.902); however:
  Package xserver-xorg-core is not configured yet.
  Package xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid which provides xserver-xorg-core is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-video-fbdev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-video-nouveau:
 xserver-xorg-video-nouveau depends on xorg-video-abi-20; however:
  Package xorg-video-abi-20 is not installed.
  Package xserver-xorg-core which provides xorg-video-abi-20 is not configured yet.
 xserver-xorg-video-nouveau depends on xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.99.902); however:
  Package xserver-xorg-core is not configured yet.
  Package xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid which provides xserver-xorg-core is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-video-nouveau (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-video-vesa:
 xserver-xorg-video-vesa depends on xorg-video-abi-20; however:
  Package xorg-video-abi-20 is not installed.
  Package xserver-xorg-core which provides xorg-video-abi-20 is not configured yet.
 xserver-xorg-video-vesa depends on xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.99.902); however:
  Package xserver-xorg-core is not configured yet.
  Package xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid which provides xserver-xorg-core is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-video-vesa (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-video-vmware:
 xserver-xorg-video-vmware depends on xorg-video-abi-20; however:
  Package xorg-video-abi-20 is not installed.
  Package xserver-xorg-core which provides xorg-video-abi-20 is not configured yet.
 xserver-xorg-video-vmware depends on xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.99.902); however:
  Package xserver-xorg-core is not configured yet.
  Package xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid which provides xserver-xorg-core is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-video-vmware (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-video-all:
 xserver-xorg-video-all depends on xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu; however:
  Package xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu is not configured yet.
 xserver-xorg-video-all depends on xserver-xorg-video-ati; however:
  Package xserver-xorg-video-ati is not configured yet.
 xserver-xorg-video-all depends on xserver-xorg-video-fbdev; however:
  Package xserver-xorg-video-fbdev is not configured yet.
 xserver-xorg-video-all depends on xserver-xorg-video-nouveau; however:
  Package xserver-xorg-video-nouveau is not configured yet.
 xserver-xorg-video-all depends on xserver-xorg-video-vesa; however:
  Package xserver-xorg-video-vesa is not configured yet.
 xserver-xorg-video-all depends on xserver-xorg-video-vmware; however:
  Package xserver-xorg-video-vmware is not configured yet.
  Package xserver-xorg-video-vmware-lts-vivid which provides xserver-xorg-video-vmware is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-video-all (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-video-cirrus:
 xserver-xorg-video-cirrus depends on xorg-video-abi-20; however:
  Package xorg-video-abi-20 is not installed.
  Package xserver-xorg-core which provides xorg-video-abi-20 is not configured yet.
 xserver-xorg-video-cirrus depends on xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.99.902); however:
  Package xserver-xorg-core is not configured yet.
  Package xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid which provides xserver-xorg-core is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-video-cirrus (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-video-intel:
 xserver-xorg-video-intel depends on xorg-video-abi-20; however:
  Package xorg-video-abi-20 is not installed.
  Package xserver-xorg-core which provides xorg-video-abi-20 is not configured yet.
 xserver-xorg-video-intel depends on xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.99.902); however:
  Package xserver-xorg-core is not configured yet.
  Package xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid which provides xserver-xorg-core is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-video-intel (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-video-mach64:
 xserver-xorg-video-mach64 depends on xorg-video-abi-20; however:
  Package xorg-video-abi-20 is not installed.
  Package xserver-xorg-core which provides xorg-video-abi-20 is not configured yet.
 xserver-xorg-video-mach64 depends on xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.99.902); however:
  Package xserver-xorg-core is not configured yet.
  Package xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid which provides xserver-xorg-core is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-video-mach64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-video-mga:
 xserver-xorg-video-mga depends on xorg-video-abi-20; however:
  Package xorg-video-abi-20 is not installed.
  Package xserver-xorg-core which provides xorg-video-abi-20 is not configured yet.
 xserver-xorg-video-mga depends on xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.99.902); however:
  Package xserver-xorg-core is not configured yet.
  Package xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid which provides xserver-xorg-core is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-video-mga (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-video-neomagic:
 xserver-xorg-video-neomagic depends on xorg-video-abi-20; however:
  Package xorg-video-abi-20 is not installed.
  Package xserver-xorg-core which provides xorg-video-abi-20 is not configured yet.
 xserver-xorg-video-neomagic depends on xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.99.902); however:
  Package xserver-xorg-core is not configured yet.
  Package xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid which provides xserver-xorg-core is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-video-neomagic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-video-openchrome:
 xserver-xorg-video-openchrome depends on xorg-video-abi-20; however:
  Package xorg-video-abi-20 is not installed.
  Package xserver-xorg-core which provides xorg-video-abi-20 is not configured yet.
 xserver-xorg-video-openchrome depends on xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.99.902); however:
  Package xserver-xorg-core is not configured yet.
  Package xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid which provides xserver-xorg-core is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-video-openchrome (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-video-qxl:
 xserver-xorg-video-qxl depends on xorg-video-abi-20; however:
  Package xorg-video-abi-20 is not installed.
  Package xserver-xorg-core which provides xorg-video-abi-20 is not configured yet.
 xserver-xorg-video-qxl depends on xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.99.902); however:
  Package xserver-xorg-core is not configured yet.
  Package xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid which provides xserver-xorg-core is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-video-qxl (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-video-r128:
 xserver-xorg-video-r128 depends on xorg-video-abi-20; however:
  Package xorg-video-abi-20 is not installed.
  Package xserver-xorg-core which provides xorg-video-abi-20 is not configured yet.
 xserver-xorg-video-r128 depends on xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.99.902); however:
  Package xserver-xorg-core is not configured yet.
  Package xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid which provides xserver-xorg-core is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-video-r128 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-video-savage:
 xserver-xorg-video-savage depends on xorg-video-abi-20; however:
  Package xorg-video-abi-20 is not installed.
  Package xserver-xorg-core which provides xorg-video-abi-20 is not configured yet.
 xserver-xorg-video-savage depends on xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.99.902); however:
  Package xserver-xorg-core is not configured yet.
  Package xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid which provides xserver-xorg-core is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-video-savage (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion:
 xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion depends on xorg-video-abi-20; however:
  Package xorg-video-abi-20 is not installed.
  Package xserver-xorg-core which provides xorg-video-abi-20 is not configured yet.
 xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion depends on xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.99.902); however:
  Package xserver-xorg-core is not configured yet.
  Package xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid which provides xserver-xorg-core is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-video-sisusb:
 xserver-xorg-video-sisusb depends on xorg-video-abi-20; however:
  Package xorg-video-abi-20 is not installed.
  Package xserver-xorg-core which provides xorg-video-abi-20 is not configured yet.
 xserver-xorg-video-sisusb depends on xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.99.902); however:
  Package xserver-xorg-core is not configured yet.
  Package xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid which provides xserver-xorg-core is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-video-sisusb (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-video-tdfx:
 xserver-xorg-video-tdfx depends on xorg-video-abi-20; however:
  Package xorg-video-abi-20 is not installed.
  Package xserver-xorg-core which provides xorg-video-abi-20 is not configured yet.
 xserver-xorg-video-tdfx depends on xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.99.902); however:
  Package xserver-xorg-core is not configured yet.
  Package xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid which provides xserver-xorg-core is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-video-tdfx (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-video-trident:
 xserver-xorg-video-trident depends on xorg-video-abi-20; however:
  Package xorg-video-abi-20 is not installed.
  Package xserver-xorg-core which provides xorg-video-abi-20 is not configured yet.
 xserver-xorg-video-trident depends on xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.99.902); however:
  Package xserver-xorg-core is not configured yet.
  Package xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid which provides xserver-xorg-core is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-video-trident (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-core-lts-xenial:
 xserver-xorg-core-lts-xenial depends on xserver-xorg-core; however:
  Package xserver-xorg-core is not configured yet.
  Package xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid which provides xserver-xorg-core is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-core-lts-xenial (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-xenial:
 xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-xenial depends on xserver-xorg-input-all; however:
  Package xserver-xorg-input-all is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-xenial (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-lts-xenial:
 xserver-xorg-lts-xenial depends on xserver-xorg; however:
  Package xserver-xorg is not configured yet.
  Package xserver-xorg-lts-vivid which provides xserver-xorg is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-lts-xenial (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 keyboard-configuration
 console-setup
 kbd
 console-setup-linux
 ubuntu-minimal
 xserver-xorg-core
 xserver-xorg-input-evdev
 xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
 xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse
 xserver-xorg-input-wacom
 xserver-xorg-input-all
 xserver-xorg
 xorg
 ubuntu-desktop
 xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu
 xserver-xorg-video-radeon
 xserver-xorg-video-ati
 xserver-xorg-video-fbdev
 xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
 xserver-xorg-video-vesa
 xserver-xorg-video-vmware
 xserver-xorg-video-all
 xserver-xorg-video-cirrus
 xserver-xorg-video-intel
 xserver-xorg-video-mach64
 xserver-xorg-video-mga
 xserver-xorg-video-neomagic
 xserver-xorg-video-openchrome
 xserver-xorg-video-qxl
 xserver-xorg-video-r128
 xserver-xorg-video-savage
 xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion
 xserver-xorg-video-sisusb
 xserver-xorg-video-tdfx
 xserver-xorg-video-trident
 xserver-xorg-core-lts-xenial
 xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-xenial
 xserver-xorg-lts-xenial
```

Comment: it is easier to do a fresh install then to fix a failed upgrade.

Comment: I really need to avoid reinstalling everything when I need to upgrade

Comment: it seems that the installation of the package keyboard-configuration went wrong ...

Comment: You can try - http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/apt-get-how-to-fix-very-broken-packages/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably too late, but it might be useful for some of you.
I had the exact same problem, and I realized that one of my environment variable was broken,leading to the exact same problem.

I found out by typing:

```
env | grep UTF
```

which gave me, if I remember well:

```
LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=fr_FR.UTF-8 git
```

Then I did:

```
export LANGUAGE=fr_FR
```

and I was able to proceed with apt-get.
[finally I reinstalled the whole distribution, but at least that problem was solved...]

Comment: I just got this problem again and your solution fixed it !! Well done @pierre-jeanarduin

Comment: Actually it partially fixed the problem : the error is not there anymore but Ubuntu still doesn't boot (black screen)