# apt upgrade error

Tags: 16.04, apt

I am trying to upgrade ubuntu 16.04 and I get this error, can you help please ?

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libgsoap8 libvncserver1 linux-headers-4.4.0-116
  linux-headers-4.4.0-116-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-119
  linux-headers-4.4.0-119-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-121
  linux-headers-4.4.0-121-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-124
  linux-headers-4.4.0-124-generic linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic linux-image-4.4.0-121-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-124-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-116-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-121-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-124-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages have been kept back:
  python-qgis python-qgis-common qgis qgis-common qgis-plugin-grass-common
  qgis-provider-grass qgis-providers qgis-providers-common
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [O/n] O
Setting up keyboard-configuration (1.108ubuntu15.4) ...
git: 'LC_CTYPE=fr_FR.UTF-8' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
dpkg: error processing package keyboard-configuration (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of console-setup-linux:
 console-setup-linux depends on keyboard-configuration (= 1.108ubuntu15.4); however:
  Package keyboard-configuration is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package console-setup-linux (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of console-setup:
 console-setup depends on console-setup-linux; however:
  Package console-setup-linux is not configured yet.
 console-setup depends on keyboard-configuration (= 1.108ubuntu15.4); however:
  Package keyboard-configuration is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package console-setup (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                    Errors were encountered while processing:
 keyboard-configuration
 console-setup-linux
 console-setup
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

EDIT: This partially fixed my issue : https://askubuntu.com/a/881860/130482. There is no more error but now Ubuntu won't boot : black screen

Comment: did you try `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f` ?

Comment: Doesnt work. Still have the same errors

Comment: See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/422264/how-to-debug-dpkg-configure-error-in-subprocess-post-installation

Comment: What ? Should I really edit the dpkg files ?? :(

Comment: Which file should I edit and what line for my case ? Please give me more specific

Comment: This partially fixed the issue https://askubuntu.com/a/881860/130482. Now there is no error but Ubuntu won't boot...black screen